# Changing an value in a dictionary python 2.7

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, dictionary, tuples

I am making a fake ATM simulator. I have the following code which will be saved to a file and store pretend users names, pins and balances.

```
bank = {'bob':[1122,0],'fred':[2211,0]}
```

When the program runs if the user deposits money (for instance bob deposits `£10`) I need the second value to update. so it would read `'bob':[1122,10]`

I am quite new to coding, I have tried  - `bank.values [0][1]` = `10` but that did not work.

Comment: You should Google for a Python dictionary tutorial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You reference a dictionary through its *keys* and not indices (like with lists or tuples). You can simply do:

```
bank['bob'][1] = 10  # 'bob' is the key
```

Comment: Yes that updated the value and now works perfectly. Brilliant.

Answer (score 4):

**The error in your program**

You are missing the call ... It is `bank.values()` which returns the list of values and not `bank.values`. But it is the wrong way of doing it as you will be losing the order of the inserted values so `[0]` is necessarily not the first value.

**Correct way of doing it**

The correct way of doing it and it should be

```
>>> bank['bob'][1] = 10
>>> bank['bob'][1]
10
```

**Small Thought** - *Updating the account balance*

`bank['bob'][1] = 10` will only override the original contents of the list. So if bob again deposits `20`, then his balance will be `20` only and not `10+20` which is `30`. So you should instead do

```
>>> bank['bob'][1] += 10
```

The next deposit will become

```
>>> bank['bob'][1] += 20
```

So in this way you can actually store the balance accurately

Comment: Geezus 3 downvotes in 46 seconds. This answer is closest to the OP's problem, guys.

Comment: Well, FWIW, you're definitely the most complete, accurate, and _helpful_ answer--to say nothing of actually fixing the call to `.values` in the OP's question. +1 from me.

Comment: @imallett Thanks ... But more people have disagreed on this. Hopefully, they leave a comment below

Comment: Was going to add += too. Saved me a job ;)

Comment: @BhargavRao, way too lazy today for proper grammar!

Answer (score 1):

Forget about manually creating 0's, just append values when a payment is added using the key/customer name:

```
bank = {'bob':[1122],'fred':[2211]}

bank["bob"].append(10) # append to bobs list

print(bank)
{'fred': [2211], 'bob': [1122, 10]}
```

Also `bank.values` does not actually call the method. You are missing the parens needed to call the method `bank.values()`, but as I already mentioned appending is a much easier solution.

Using `bank['bob'][1] = 10` means you will always change the second element so you will never be able to add more than the two values as the assignment will just overwrite the previous value.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot depend on the order of a dictionary because they are unordered containers. Therefore you cannot access a given item using an index, because the index is meaningless (as it would imply order). You would have to change the value using the key to retrieve the item.

```
bank['bob'] = [1122, 10]
```

Or to modify just the second item

```
bank['bob'][1] = 10
```